# Finding last few distinct records in Sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

Here is my simplified database layout in SQLServer:

**Table Books:**

```
BookID  BookName
......  .........
```

**Table Reviewers:**

```
ReviewerID  ReviewerName
..........  ............
```

**Table Reviews:**

```
BookID  ReviewerID  ReviewDate  Notes
......  ..........  ..........  .....
```

I need to find out last 3 "unique" books that were reviewed. For example, if the review order was `book-a, book-b, book-c, book-c, book-d`, the output should be `book-d, book-c, and book-b`.

None of the queries I tried seem to work. The inner join to get the name of the book complicates it further. Would appreciate your guidance. Regards.

Comment: Post some sample data and the queries you tried

Comment: How about posting some of those failed queries here? Perhaps only a minor change is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written logic inside the query. I have also given how to use(ie, `JOIN`) the result with your other tables.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
    -- Get sequence number for all dates for each BOOKID in descending order
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BOOKID ORDER BY REVIEWDATE DESC)RNO      
    FROM [Table Reviews]
)
SELECT TOP 3 TB.BOOKNAME,TR.ReviewerName [LastReviewedBy],C.ReviewDate [LastReviewDate]
FROM CTE C
JOIN [Table Books] TB ON C.BOOKID=TB.BOOKID
JOIN [Table Reviewers] TR ON C.ReviewerID=TR.ReviewerID
WHERE RNO=1
ORDER BY DATEORDER DESC
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1150e/1) to view result

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. Marking this as an answer because of the depth and the details.

Comment: Welcome. Feel free to ask for any changes. :) @Peter

Answer (score 2):

That can be achieved with many methods.

You can give it a try with ROW_NUMBER function for example:

Not sure this is 100% correct, try to supply sqlfiddles, will help others help you.

```
select TOP 3
    *
from (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                BookID
            ORDER BY
                ReviewDate DESC
        ) reviewOrder,
        *
    from Reviews
) R
where
    reviewOrder = 1
order by
    ReviewDate DESC
```